# Get Month and Day value from valid gMonthDay format without splitting

Tags: c#

I have an input as --12-21(Valid gMonthDay Format). In this 12 is the Month and 21 is the Day Value.
I want to show the output as DD/MM value which can be achieved easily by splitting the value. But i don't want to hard-code it in the code.

Can anyone please suggest a different approach  which would work in all scenarios .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't want to hard-code what?

Comment: @rae1n Splitting the input and then getting Month and day out of it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use something like this

```
string gMonthDay = "--12-21";
string output = DateTime.ParseExact(gMonthDay, "--MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd/MM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```